# How to ask sbt to only fetch dependencies, without compiling?

Tags: docker, sbt

Is there a way to only download the dependencies but do not compile source.

I am asking because I am trying to build a Docker build environment for my bigger project. 
The Idear is that during `docker build` I clone the project, download all dependencies and then delete the code.
Then use `docker run -v` to mount the frequently changing code into the docker container and start compiling the project.

Currently I just compile the code during build and then compile it again on run. The problem ist that when a dependencie changes I have to build from scratch and that takes a long time.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Run sbt's `update` command. Dependencies will be resolved and retrieved.

Comment: This answer is correct for this question and should me marked so. However, it does not download plugins.

Comment: @Abhishek not sure what you mean. `update` can't run until the build definition has loaded, which can't happen unless plugins have been downloaded.