# How to download only sbt dependencies into sbt local cache without build of jars?

Tags: scala, sbt

is is possible to execute such command in sbt to download all jar dependencies (needed for `assembly` task without build actual target jar? I would like to fullfill local cache (I mean `~/.sbt`, `~/.m2` and so on directories). Is there exist such command or way to do it?

Comment: take a look to all the available plugins https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html

Comment: What is name of this plugin?

Comment: Try https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack

Comment: This sounds like `sbt update`.

Comment: duplicate of [How to ask sbt to only fetch dependencies, without compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807674/how-to-ask-sbt-to-only-fetch-dependencies-without-compiling)

Answer (score 2):

The sbt `update` task does this. This is listed in the sbt Command Line Reference, under [Project-level Tasks](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Project-level+tasks).